# To many Parens on calculated field?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Am I overdoing it with parens?

```
=IF((app_pr_apr01_status=""),"",IF((app_pr_apr01_status="approved"),"approved","pending"))
```

Basically

- if app_pr_apr01_status = "" then field = ""
- if app_pr_apr01_status = "approved" then field = "approved"
- Else it = "pending"

Comment: What's the issue in the above formula? it should work!

Comment: was just wondering if I needed all those parens

Answer (score 2):

**Actually,** it is not a big issue, you just try to write a formula that matches your needs, you can add additionally "nested if"if your current requirements require that.

**Example:**

- If Status is `Empty`, then ""
- If Status is `Approved`, then "Approved"
- If Status is `Consumed`, then "Consumed"
- Otherwise `Pending`

**[Fomula]**

```
=IF((Status=""),"",IF((Status="approved"),"approved",IF((Status="Consumed"),"Consumed","pending")))
```

**[Output]**

[image]

---

**But** if you need to write your mentioned formula,

**[Fomula]**

```
=IF((Status=""),"",IF((Status="approved"),"approved","pending"))
```

**[The output]**

[image]

In another way, try the following

**[Fomula]**

```
=IF(AND(NOT(Status=""),NOT(Status="approved")),"pending",Status)
```

**In this case,** if it's not `approved` and not `Empty`, show the value of the `Pending`, otherwise, show `Status` field

**[The same output]**

[image]

This formula is different than your formula, but it would give you the same result,

**So Formula style depends on**

- The current requirements,
- The available functions,
- The thinking way.

Check also [THE SUPPORTED AND UNSUPPORTED COLUMNS IN SHAREPOINT CALCULATED COLUMN FORMULA](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)